# Convert every nth element of an array to an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I'd like to convert:

```
var people = [1,"Shaw","Tanzania",2,"Nelson","Kazakhstan",3,"Garcia","Madagascar"]
```

into:

```
var rows = [
    [1, "Shaw", "Tanzania"],
    [2, "Nelson", "Kazakhstan"],
    [3, "Garcia", "Madagascar"]
];
```

I've seen this answer to a similar question, but I don't understand how that works and extend it to every nth element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a for loop with [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). You iterate the original array using the require chunk size as the step. On each iteration you slice the relevant part from the original array (slice doesn't mutate the array), and push it into the result array.

```js
var people = [1,"Shaw","Tanzania",2,"Nelson","Kazakhstan",3,"Garcia","Madagascar"];

var result = [];
var chunkSize = 3;

for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i+= chunkSize) {
  result.push(people.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
}

console.log(result);
```